# Resizing/compressing animated GIF in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, image-processing, graphics

I have a uiimagepicker that picks a picture and uploads it to server it serializes the image as gif or jpeg. with jpeg i use UIGraphics to resize the image before upload. In case of animated gif it loses its animation once resized. is there a way to resize the gif in swift or even reduce the size somehow?